# How to save a particular datetime format while saving csv?

Tags: pandas

I have a CSV file where date is given in `%d-%m-%Y` format. I would like the date to appear in `%Y-%m-%d` format in CSV.

Thus, I changed the date column to datetime through python and then changed it to str and saved the CSV but it is
still showing the older format i.e. `%d-%m-%Y`

This is the main csv file [image]

After running this line of code

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
```

I again saw the same format in the CSV i.e. 11-06-2020 (11th June 2020)

Comment: try firstly `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')` then `df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: It should have been df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') . This is not working too

Comment: kindly post data as text

Answer (score 1):

you can set this format on the excel writer engine

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html#ex-pandas-datetime

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='yyyy-mm-dd')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```